# Need permissions to delete event log

Tags: command-line, permissions, windows-11, event-viewer

I have an application that I wanted to delete but when I tried doing so, it said that it couldn't be deleted because was open in the event log.

Since I didn't want to do it manually, I found this command line that would delete it for me in command prompt:

`for /F "tokens=*" %1 in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO wevtutil.exe cl "%1"`

When I try running it however, it fails because access is denied.

How can I set permissions to make it so that this code can delete my logs? Is this the correct solution to my initial problem, or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[Wevutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wevtutil) is a Microsoft utility that

> Enables you to retrieve information about event logs and publishers

I don't really see a reason to remove it in the first place.

The error you almost-quoted ("couldn't be deleted because was open in the event log"... please do always put in exact error messages) says `webutil.exe` is running. You should be able to simply kill it with Task Manager, then remove it. However if it's installed and running by default on Win 11, next system update may very well reinstall and re-enable it.